# Foundation, nav bg

Tags: html, css, web, frameworks, zurb-foundation

I am working with Foundation for the very first time for one of my college assignments. After extensive tests and solution searching, I think I finally have to ask for help.

How do I alter the background-color of section class="top-bar-section"? I've been trying to temper with it in CSS, but nothing has worked. =(

```
<section class="top-bar-section">
            <ul class="left">
              <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 9</a></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
```

Comment: y can't u try use a custom style sheet to fix this issue, like".top-bar-section{background-color:#ff0000;}"

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried. And the result was, I'm sad to say, fruitless.

Comment: give a try to force the customized class with "!important" like .top-bar-section{background-color:#ff0000!important;}"

Comment: The background color is applied via the nav class .top-bar, not the section. Try .top-bar { background: your-color; }